# Canned Coconut milk is curdled when opened

Tags: milk, fermentation, coconut, spoilage, coconut-milk

I bought Coconut milk (88% coconut and rest water) in a sealed can, when I opened it the solid where already separated from the liquid. The solid part was at the top quite thick like frozen coconut oil.

It tastes perhaps (I am not sure) a little bit acidic. Has the coconut milk spoilt? Is there any use of it or I should just throw it? Can consuming it be harmful?

Comment: That's normal. The coconut oil and the coconut water won't stay mixed. It's not curdled at all.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I didn't notice an exact duplicate of this question anywhere, but it's quite common for canned coconut milk to separate leaving an opaque white solid layer of fat and solids, and a thin watery/syrup layer of cloudy coconut water.

Coconut water is naturally a little tart, so I don't find that concerning. If the can is in date and showed no signs of swelling or leakage, then I'm thinking it's fine.

But do what makes you feel comfortable/safe. And to avoid this next time, thoroughly shake the can before opening.

Comment: Before you shake the can look at your recipe, some call for spooning the cream off the top and frying it off with pastes or spices.

Comment: @GdD It sounds like frying stuff in  coconut oil.

Comment: A well split can of coconut milk will not mix by shaking it. It will need stiring at least.

Comment: @Willeke: Absolutely.  On the other hand, for many recipes (curries, soups, stews) it doesn’t need mixing — it will mix during cooking anyway.

Comment: Normally I find it very pleasant to open canned coconut milk because there is almost nothing stuck to the lid (because there is a solid layer of fat at the top). Shaking it before opening will make can-opening much messier and less satisfying, I would never do that.